# AutoML Vision train logo detection

Tags: google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl

I was wondering if there is some kind of documentation available for Google's AutoML Vision to train recognizing specific logo's.

At this point I only can find documentation about [object detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/prepare).

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? Do you want to compare logo or with some animals, logos with specific text or something like that? Could you provide example of logo and what exactly you want to achieve? There is documentation about detecting [Logos](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-logos) but what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I wan't to detect a Company logo, if I upload photos of Coca Cola bottles it recognises the Coca Cola logo. If I upload a logo for an other large company it doesn't get recognised. So I hope I can train Google Cloud Vision with AutoML Vision to recognise the Company of the logo.

Comment: Did you try to use [Detect Logos](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-logos) from my previous comment? On the bottom of the page you have [Try It](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-logos#try_it) option which recognizes logos without text (like GENERAL ELECTRIC, Shell, Nike). I guess this would work for you.

Comment: Yes I tried it but it does not recognise my logo thats the whole problem. So I wan't to add a new logo to the library of Google Cloud Vision with AutoML. So it can get recognised with the Detect Logos function from Google.

Comment: I assume it's not popular logo? So you want to recognize some local logos, not known/worldwide logos?

Comment: Yes, its a very popular logo in my country but not world wide.

Comment: Could you advise which one is it?

Comment: @PjoterS I don't see why that's relevant, it is a big companies brand logo and at this moment it does not get recognised. Is this possible with AutoML to train the model to recognise the logo and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google already has a feature to detect popular product logos within an image - [Detect logos](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-logos). However it's managed by google and you won't find all logos there. It will recognize worldwide/know logos like GENERAL ELECTRIC, Shell, Nike.

There is also a [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159600659) - `Feature Request` which could give the possibility of modifying `Vision API` logo detection. You can `star` it to show you would also like this feature.

To achieve what you want, to recognise less known logos, you would need the AutoML train as you mention.

In [AutoML Vision API Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tutorial) you can find some general information about training, however to your scenario I would suggest you to follow [Building Image Detection with Google Cloud AutoML](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-image-detection-with-google-cloud-automl-8b9cf2b8074b) guide where `Image Detection` was used (open in private view in the browser if you have limitations).

You will find there all steps from `Gathering Images` through `Image Labelling`, `Model Training`, `Model Evaluation` to `Outputs` and `Conclusions`.

In this case you would need to use AutoML from scratch so you would need to train it using all logos.